# How can I set "IsSiteAdmin" property true for a user using Webservice/REST API for Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive

I need to know how I can set *IsSiteAdmin* property to true for a user in my O365 setup using REST API for Sharepoint or any webservice for that matter. I can do this via Powershell but I'm looking for a solution through APIs.

### Update 1

Sorry for being vague, the question actually is that whether or not an Admin (Company Administrator) assign a user(say himself) who is *NOT* a site user on a Site as Site Collection Admin for the OneDrive(my site) for other tenant users.

Let's say that admin is *abc@mytenant@onmicrosoft.com* and there is a user say *pqr@mytenant@onmicrosoft.com*. The OneDrive(my site) for this user would be;

```
https://mytenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/prq_onmicrosoft_com
```

Can I make abc@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com (who is NOT a site user on pqr@mytenant@onmicrosoft.com) a Site Collection Administrator on this site?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Endpoint Uri**: `/_api/web/siteUsers/getByLoginName(@u)?@u='userloginName'`

**Method**: `POST`

**Body**: `{ '__metadata':{ 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'IsSiteAdmin':'true' }`

**Headers**:

- `"content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"`
- `"X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"`

**JavaScript example**

```
function updateUser(loginName, properties)
{
    var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/siteUsers/getByLoginName(@u)?@u='" + encodeURIComponent(loginName) + "'";
    var userPayload  = { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }};
    for(var p in properties)
       userPayload[p] = properties[p];
    var headers = {};
    headers["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
    return executeRequest(endpointUrl,'POST',headers,userPayload);
}
```

where

```
function executeRequest(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    if (typeof headers == 'undefined'){
        headers = {};
    }
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST" || method == "PUT") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(method == "POST" || method == "PUT") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  
    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

Usage

```
var loginName = 'i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com';
var properties = {'IsSiteAdmin': true};
updateUser(loginName,properties)
   .done(function(value){
       console.log('User has been assigned as site collection admin');
   })
   .fail(function(error){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   });
```

### References

[Users, groups, and roles REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_User)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have already tried this, but for my scenario, it doesn't work. I have updated my question, can you please take a look?